# How to see remote console of my bot at VPS?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js, bots

I have my discord bot, and i hosted it at VPS.
I writing my js scripts for bot (node.js) via VS Code, and I have “Remote SSH” plugin for applying changes immediately.
I have ftp and ssh options for connect to my VPS.

But I have next issue:
When I’m coding, I open VS Code, connecting to my server, after I have finish my changes I start command “forever start index.js” (it’s need for bot will be always online), I’m closing VS Code. Bot working perfectly.
But when I open VS Code again, and connecting via “Remote SSH” plugin, I can make a change in my scripts, but I don’t see anything in console( only one solution what I found is: stop my bot, then just start by “node index.js”), and when I will finish coding press “ctrl + c”, then type “forever start index.js”
But it’s bad for me, cz my bot has some timeout tasks and other stuffs(

I mean: I see any “console.log()” messages only when I open vscode, then typing “forever stop index.js”, then type “node index.js”.. but I can’t see anything in console if I close vscode and open again( looks like bot wanna stay alive without me..

I don’t see any message in console when I connecting to already working bot.

How I can see console of my already working bot on VPS without restarting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting your program with forever, there's options to log information to a specified file.

From [here](https://github.com/foreversd/forever)

```
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

For example, you can start your bot like this

```js
forever start -l logs.txt my-script.js
```

Comment: Yes, but may be any option to see console.log in terminal online? Imagine: I can connect to my remote server with terminal via ssh. Ok, we are there. Then I can start my bot with using command “node index.js”, done. And until I here (in this terminal session) I see every “console.log()” message. But if I’ll close the terminal window - my bot will be offline. So, I connecting to remote server with using terminal via ssh, start my bot with using “forever start index.js” and see any console.log() message, until I’ll close the terminal window. I finished with code, closed terminal, bot still works

Comment: But when I reconnecting to my already working bot - I can’t see any console.log() message..